# Creating a sensor that checks for objects matching a wildcard in specified GCS location

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have a requirement to create a dag that senses an Object in a GCS Bucket using wildcards.
e.g. the task should check if a file is present at the specified GCS location every 1 hour, if the file is present matching the provided wildcards, it should trigger the next task otherwise it should be marked as up for schedule and check again after 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

The wildcards are not supported in the gcs hooks and sensors, to do that, you can create a custom sensor which uses the hook `airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs.GCSHook` to list all the files in some prefix, then uses regix to check if there is a file path that match provided wildcard.

```py
from re import match
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs import GCSHook

class CustomGcsSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
...
    def poke(self, context):
        prefix = "some/constant/prefix/" # used to reduce the list size, you can skip it if you have regex in all the prefix
        wildcard = ".*/images/.*\.jpg" # */images/*.jpg
        gcs_hook = GCSHook(...) # use a connection
        files = gcs_hook.list(bucket_name=..., prefix=prefix) # for some use cases you can use a delimiter like delimiter='.jpg'
        matched_files = list(filter(lambda file_path: match(wildcard, file_path.replace(prefix, "")), files))
        return len(matched_files) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [GCSObjectExistenceSensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/google/cloud/sensors/gcs.py#L46), which supports match_glob. This supports the wildcards defined in [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list#list-objects-and-prefixes-using-glob).